# Finding duplicate elements in a Scheme List using recursion

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I'm trying to create a function that will check a list of numbers for duplicates and return either #t or #f. I can only use car, cdr and conditionals, no cons. 
This is what I have so far but it's giving me the error "car: contract violation expected: pair? given: #f"

```
(define (dups a)
    (if (null? a)
        #f
        (if (= (car a)(car(dups(cdr a))))
            #t
            (dups (cdr))
        )
    )
)
```

I'm new to both scheme and recursion, any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error? Post it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `if` doesn't make much sense. I'm assuming you wanted to check whether `(car a)` appears somewhere further down the list, but `(car (dups (cdr a)))` doesn't give you that. Also, `(car (dups ...))` is a type-issue since `dups` will return a boolean instead of a list, and `car` is expecting a list (or actually, a pair, which is what lists are composed of).

What you need is a second function to call in the test of that second if. That function takes an element and a list and searches for that element in the list. Of course, if you're allowed, use `find`, otherwise implement some sort of `my-find` - it's quite simple and similar to your `dups` function.